# Simple python 3 programming. explain my error

Tags: python

I am new to python. Why Does this not work?

```
fin = open("words.txt")
for lines in fin:
    word = lines.strip()
    if has_no_e(word) == True:
        print(word)


def has_no_e(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e":
            return False
    return True
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/john/PycharmProjects/test/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    if has_no_e(word) == True:
NameError: name 'has_no_e' is not defined
```

Comment: You're trying to call `has_no_e` before you define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop runs before the function is defined, so the name `has_no_e` doesn't exist yet.

Put the function definition *first*:

```
def has_no_e(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e":
            return False
    return True

fin = open("words.txt")
for lines in fin:
    word = lines.strip()
    if has_no_e(word) == True:
        print(word)
```

You could just use a *containment test* to find if the letter `e` is present:

```
def has_no_e(word):
    return 'e' not in word
```

`not in` does what your function does; loop through all characters in `word` and return `False` if one of those characters is `e`.

I'd use a `with` statement to ensure that the file is closed again after your `for` loop is done. You don't need to use `== True`; the `if` statement already tests for truth:

```
with open("words.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if has_no_e(word):
            print(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to move your definition above your code. A common way to fix this type of issue before it pops up is with a `main` method that is called at the end of your script. This will gaurantee everything is defined properly before execution while still keeping your code in a logical/preferred order.

```
def main():
  fin = open("words.txt")
  for lines in fin:
      word = lines.strip()
      if has_no_e(word) == True:
          print(word)


def has_no_e(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e":
            return False
    return True

main()
```

Alternatively, simply move your code around

```
def has_no_e(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e":
            return False
    return True

fin = open("words.txt")
for lines in fin:
    word = lines.strip()
    if has_no_e(word) == True:
        print(word)
```